# How to make pandas read_csv distinguish strings based on quoting

Tags: python, parsing, csv, pandas

I want pandas.io.parsers.read_csv to distinguish between strings and the rest of data types based on the fact that strings in my csv file are always `"quoted"`. Is it possible?
I have the following csv example:

```
"ID"|"DATE"|"NAME"|"YEAR"|"FLOAT"|"BOOL"
"01"|2000-01-01|"Name1"|1975|1.2|1
"02"||""||||
```

It should give me a dataframe where all the quoted guys are strings. Most likely pandas will make everything else np.float64, but I could deal with it afterwards. I want to wait with using `dtype`, because I have many columns, and I don't want to map types for all of them. I would like to try to make it only `"quote"`-based, if possible.

I tried to use `quotechar='"'` and `quoting=3`, but `quotechar` doesn't do anything at all, while `quoting` keeps `""` which I don't want as well.  It seems to me pandas parsers should be able to do it, since this is the way to distinguish strings in csv files.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying dtypes would be the more straightforward way, but if you don't want to do that I'd suggest using `quoting=3` and cleaning up afterwards.

```
strip_char = lambda x: x.strip('"')

In [40]: df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), sep='|', quoting=3)

In [41]: df
Out[41]: 
   "ID"      "DATE"   "NAME"  "YEAR"  "FLOAT"  "BOOL"
0  "01"  2000-01-01  "Name1"    1975      1.2       1
1  "02"         NaN       ""     NaN      NaN     NaN

[2 rows x 6 columns]

In [42]: df = df.rename(columns=strip_char)

In [43]: df[['ID', 'NAME']] = df[['ID', 'NAME']].applymap(strip_char)

In [44]: df
Out[44]: 
   ID        DATE   NAME  YEAR  FLOAT  BOOL
0  01  2000-01-01  Name1  1975    1.2     1
1  02         NaN          NaN    NaN   NaN

[2 rows x 6 columns]

In [45]: df.dtypes
Out[45]: 
ID        object
DATE      object
NAME      object
YEAR     float64
FLOAT    float64
BOOL     float64
dtype: object
```

EDIT: Then you can set the index:

```
In [11]: df = df.set_index('ID')

In [12]: df
Out[12]: 
          DATE   NAME  YEAR  FLOAT  BOOL
ID                                      
01  2000-01-01  Name1  1975    1.2     1
02         NaN          NaN    NaN   NaN

[2 rows x 5 columns]
```

Comment: It is a possible solution, although I cannot use it. As I mentioned in my post, `quoting=3` doesn't work in my case, since I provide `index_col` argument as well (e.g. `index_col=['ID']`) and this will raise an error if combined with `quoting=3`, since pandas after applying `quoting=3` doesn't know what's `ID` but `"ID"`. I suppose I could live with `index_col=['"%s"' % i for i in index]`, but then stripping `""` would need to be applied to `columns` and `index`. There must be a solution to such a problem, at least there should be. Most of the time strings are quoted in csv files, aren't they?

Comment: I edited my answer to set the index. Or you can pass `index_col='"ID"'` to `read_csv` and do a similar renaming as I did with the columns. You can also refer to columns by position in `read_csv`: `index_col=0`. I agree that this isn't a great solution.